# django send json patch request during test

Tags: django

I am using django 3.0. Here is my view that I am trying to test:

```
def myview(request):
   values = {}
   if request.method == 'PATCH':
        keys = QueryDict(request.body)
        print(keys)
        for key in keys:
            cache.set(key, keys[key], timeout=300)
            values[key] = keys[key]
        return JsonResponse(values, status=200)
```

and my test case:

```
class ValueViewTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()

    def test_value_updated(self):
        data = {'key_1': 'updated_val'}
        response = self.c.patch('/values/', data)
        print(response.json())
        # self.assertEqual(response.json(), data)  # ->>  test failing
```

console logs:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
<QueryDict: {'{"key_1": "updated_val"}': ['']}>
{'{"key_1": "updated_val"}': ''}
```

I want to send data as key value pair, but somehow it malformed , right now whole request acting as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data format is wrong.

A querydict would not contain a json, but a sequence of request parameters like `key_1=1&key_2=2&key3=3`. Try this:

```
def test_value_updated(self):
    data = 'key_1=1&key_2=2&key3=3'
    response = self.c.patch('/values/', data)
    print(response.json())
```

Hope this helps.